# Semantic-ui search - access object properties not used in 'searchFields'

Tags: semantic-ui

I am using the Semantic UI search for the `title` property of my `data` object. `data` has other fields and I want to access them when an object is selected. For example, I want to put the value from the `uuid` property in a hidden input.

Is there a Semantic UI way of doing this? - I couldn't figure it out from the [documentation](http://semantic-ui.com/modules/search.html#/settings) (I know I can go and search through all `data.title`'s for the selected one, but ... there probably is another way).

```
$('.ui.search').search({
        source: data,
        searchFields: [
          'title'
        ]
        ,onSelect : function(event){
          //...some other code
          $("#tags").append('<input type="hidden" value="'+ value_from_my_uuid_field +'"');
        }
  });


 <div class="ui search">
    <div class="ui icon input">
        <i class="search icon"></i>
        <input class="prompt" type="text" placeholder="Search subjects...">
    </div>
    <div class="results"></div>
  </div>
```

Thank you.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The search widget has an `onSelect` callback you can register ([docs](http://semantic-ui.com/modules/search.html#search)) When your user selects a suggestion from the search response, your callback will be called with the selection:

```
$searchWidget.search({
        onSelect: function(result) {
            // do something with result.id or whatever
        }
    });
```

Comment: I know `onSelect` exists - I have it in my question. At the time of the question, `onSelect` did not give me access to other data fields besides the searched field. Has this behavior changed in the last Semantic UI version?

Comment: I believe so, looking closer at your question, the sample code you provided seems to indicate that the onSelect callback used get an event. Now it gets objects representing the selection, and choices available.

Comment: Yes, you are right. Thank you. I made a jsfiddle in case other people want to test this: https://jsfiddle.net/loredana_cirstea/wgjzzwyf/

Answer (score 0):

I had a similar problem (but with ajax source data) and I finally ended up adding hidden content-tags to the results (on server side) like `<div style='display:none;' class='id'>12345</div>`.

And in the onSelect-callback I search the result (with jquery) for this content:

```js
onSelect : function(event){
 var $result = $(this);

 var id = $result.find(".id").html();
 ...

 // Return 'default' triggers the default select behaviour of the search module.
 return "default";
}
```

HTH

Comment: Thanks for the idea, but I want to be able to access any object property and it can get a little crowded with hidden content. It should be a more direct way and I wanted to know if it was already implemented before I raise any issues. P.S.: I am now using `onResults(response)` callback to get the last batch of results before selection and I'm searching for my selected item among them (it offers access to all properties). Thanks again.

Answer (score 0):

Semantic UI actually provides a way of accessing any of the object's properties.
I used both `dropdown` and `search` classes, as shown in the [docs](http://semantic-ui.com/modules/dropdown.html#search-dropdown) with [hidden input values](http://semantic-ui.com/modules/dropdown.html#specifying-different-text--hidden-input-values) for the properties.

```
<template name="search_drop">
  <div class="ui floating dropdown labeled search icon button">
    <i class="search icon"></i>
    <span class="text">Search subjects...</span>
    <div class="menu">
      {{#each subjects}}
        <div class="item" data-id="{{this.id}}" data-value="{{this.value}}" data-child="{{this.haschildren}}">{{this.name}}
        </div>
      {{/each}}
    </div>
  </div>
</template>
```

`subjects` contains my objects with id, name, value, haschildren properties.

```
Template.search_drop.rendered = function(){
      $(".dropdown").dropdown({
        onChange: function(value, text, $choice){
          console.log(value); //will output the equivalent of {{this.name}}
          console.log($choice[0].attributes); //list of attributes
          console.log($choice[0].attributes["data-id"].value); //the equivalent of {{this.id}}
        }
      });
}
```